# Remove wpf black selection box around checkbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm currently using the datagridtable of WPF. I like it to instantly change the checkbox when being pressed. Now it first has to be selected and then I can change the checkbox value.

However, when I select a checkbox a weird black square appears around the check:

[image: Black selection box]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, your XAML snippet would help, also please take a minute and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is maybe not the best but the easiest, is to set 'BorderThickness="0px"'.

Set it as a style for your DataGrid to apply the behave on all cells.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0px" />
</Style>
```